# How to auto-load all pages when opening mutiple pages in Safari 15

Tags: macos, safari

After upgrading from Safari 14 to 15.0 (macOS 11.6), when I Cmd-open a bookmark folder in Safari, it no longer automatically loads all the pages in the folder in the background, but now only loads the pages when the tab is brought to the foreground. Is there a way to revert to the old behavior, so all the pages get loaded into memory immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behavior has reverted back to the previous method of opening all pages immediately, with the installation of Safari 15.2